# Kill particular gstreamer instance running in background

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, kill, pid

I have a shell script that launches multiple instances of gstreamer (for different cameras) when called from within my C program using system().
All my gstreamer instances are running in background.

Now I want to be able to get the process ID corresponding to a particular instance only and kill that instance (while not terminating other instances).

Right now, I have a kill.sh script that simply gets PID of all instances of gstreamer and closes them all.

Is there any way to do the selective killing of gstreamer instances? Any help or ideas will be really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to identify the particular instance ?

Comment: I think each instance would be identified by its process ID since all my gstreamer instances are running in background.

Comment: No. I meant how do you choose selective processes?

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess I'm not able to understand what exactly your question is.